# Mongo group by two columns and return array of values from another column

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a mongoDB that I want to query. I understand how to do this in sql but not sure how to do in MongoDB.

```
select distinct value, type,  array_agg(distribution) as distributions
from t
group by value, param_type;
```

I am trying this but keep getting an error:

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "type": "$type",
        "value": "$value"
      },
      allowDiskUse: true ,
      distribution: {
        $addToSet: "$distribution"
      }
    }
  }]
)



Failed to execute script.

Error: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "The field 'allowDiskUse' must be an accumulator object",
    "code" : 40234,
    "codeName" : "Location40234"
} : aggregate failed :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:18:14
_assertCommandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:583:17
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:673:16
DB.prototype._runAggregate@src/mongo/shell/db.js:266:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1012:12
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@:1:355
@(shell):1:1
```

Comment: it needs to be `"$type"` and not `$type`, same goes for `"$value"`.

Comment: Thanks. Still getting an error. I'll amend the question.

Comment: `lastStage` does not appear in your code snippet.

Comment: pipeline stages should be in array bracket `.aggregate([ { $group: { ... } } ])`.

Comment: Getting another error now. I'm new to mongo.

Comment: pass parameter `{ allowDiskUse: true }` in second position of aggregate `.aggregate([ { $group: { ... } } ], { allowDiskUse: true })`,

Comment: Still getting an error. I'll amend the question.

Comment: please look at my last comment for correct syntax where to put `allowDiskUse` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few fixes,

- pipeline stages should be in array bracket
- pass `allowDiskUse: true` in second parameter of `aggregate()` function, Enables writing to temporary files. When set to true, aggregation stages can write data to the `_tmp` subdirectory in the `dbPath` directory.

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate(
  [
    {
      $group: {
        _id: {
          "type": "$type",
          "value": "$value"
        },
        distribution: {
          $addToSet: "$distribution"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  { allowDiskUse: true }
);
```

There is some memory restriction [aggregation-pipeline-limits-agg-memory-restrictions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/#agg-memory-restrictions),

> **Result Size Restriction:** 
> When returning a cursor or storing the results in a collection, each document in the result set is subject to the BSON Document Size limit, currently 16 megabytes; if any single document that exceeds the BSON Document Size limit, the command will produce an error. The limit only applies to the returned documents; during the pipeline processing, the documents may exceed this size.

> **Memory Restriction:** 
> Pipeline stages have a limit of 100 megabytes of RAM. If a stage exceeds this limit, MongoDB will produce an error. To allow for the handling of large datasets, use the `allowDiskUse` option to enable aggregation pipeline stages to write data to temporary files.

Answer (score 1):

`aggregate` takes a pipeline as the first paramerter, which basically is an array of objects. So I'd try doing this:

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "type": "$type",
        "value": "$value"
      },
      distribution: {
        $addToSet: "$distribution"
      }
    }
  }
], { allowDiskUse: true })
```

Note the `([...])`. Also note `{ allowDiskUse: true }` as suggested by @turivishal

Comment: That runs but it's not returning any results.

Comment: @Sql_Pete_Belfast Is it throwing an error or just an empty result?

Comment: It was giving an error. I just didn't see it popping up on another screen. I'm amending the question

Comment: @Sql_Pete_Belfast See the updated answer for the proper syntax.